# What type of oil are on Kars' feathers?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

During his aerial fight with JoJo, Kars fires off some feathers which are as hard as an armadillo's shell and covered in a bullet deflecting oil.

[image]

I've never heard of an oil that could deflect bullets, and I can't visualize how that would even work. Is this a thing that exists, or is it just something that the writer made up?

Comment: Maybe its a magical oil. :p - or maybe the oils just really slippery possibly as well?

Comment: I had read somewhere that the Zulu put some kind of oil on their shields that made them more impervious to bullets (no idea if it actually worked). Cursory internet search brings up nothing though.

Answer (score 1):

This oil seems like some sort of oil made of a sponge-like surface that can take a lot of damage. We don't have such things in our world, but there is this sort of thread-like material used in new body armor that deflects bullets. This sort of oil could follow such physical rules possibly. Also, the anime just does things that are pretty **bizzare**, so it might be plot logic.